# How to clone project from GIT repository through Local network?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

I am trying to create a repository in one computer and access (clone/push/pull) it from other computer in which both systems were connected in the same LAN network.

I created GIT repository locally using "VCS"-->"Import into Version Control"-->"Create Git Repository" option in android studio.

[image]

I followed the steps from this link to create local git repository, https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/setting-up-a-local-git-repository.html

As of now, I have created the project and repository in one computer. 
Now, I have Android studio installed in computer 2 and now I want to clone the project from computer one to computer two (both computers were connected locally in same network).

Is it possible to clone the project from computer 1 to computer 2 locally using Android studio?

Comment: Have a look at the Git protocol: https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: Thanks @BlackEye. The above link helped me lot.

Comment: Did the link help you enough to become an answer to this question?

Comment: yes @BlackEye. The link provided sufficient information to understand about the protocols, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the Git protocol: [git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)